# Nested Form -- Can't mass assign protected attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm a little stumped by this one, cause I feel like I've dodged the common errors (like [mistyping the attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380761/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-with-nested-protected-models), or [leaving it out altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037239/nested-form-triggering-a-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-warning)), but I'm still getting a

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: home, work
```

error here. I'm guessing I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what.

At any rate, in my new app, Users have one Home and one Work (which each belong to a user), and I want users to enter them on signing up. So, in my models:

**user.rb**

```
attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :home_attributes, :work_attributes

  has_one :home, :work

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :work, :home

  has_secure_password
```

**home.rb**

```
attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longitude, :user_id
belongs_to :user

validates :address, presence: true
```

**work.rb**

```
attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longitude, :user_id
belongs_to :user

validates :address, presence: true
```

in my controller

**users_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @user = User.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { redirect_to @user }
  end
end
```

and in my form:

**views/users/_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    .error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") 
        prohibited this post from being saved:
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  = f.label :first_name
  = f.text_field :first_name

  = f.label :last_name
  = f.text_field :last_name

  = f.label :email
  = f.text_field :email

  = f.label :password
  = f.password_field :password

  = f.label :password_confirmation, "Re-Enter Password"
  = f.password_field :password_confirmation

  = f.fields_for :home do |builder|
    = builder.label :address, "Home address"
    = builder.text_field :address
  %br
  = f.fields_for :work do |builder|
    = builder.label :address, "Work address"
    = builder.text_field :address

  .btn-group
    = f.submit 'Sign Up!', class: "btn"
```

Comment: It's curious to me that the error is saying it can't assign `home` when really the parameter should be named `home_attributes`. Have you tried doing a `@user.build_home` and `@user.build_work` setup in your new action?

Comment: I tried adding these two lines -- "@home = Home.new" and "@work = Work.new" -- in my controller, then doing "f.fields_for @home do |builder|". Is that what you mean? That protests similarly.

Comment: Negative. You want to specifically build it for your @user object (`@user.build_home`, `@user.build_work`)

Comment: How do I refer to that Work/Home object in the view, then?

Comment: You wouldn't do anything different in your form. `build_home` sets the `home` property on the `@user` record so that when you do `f.fields_for :home` it's referring to what you prepared in the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you haven't set up your instance variable to include those attributes.

In your controller you should have something like this

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.homes.build
    @user.works.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { redirect_to @user }
  end
end
```

If you don't build those attributes the form doesn't know what to do.

**Edit**: Fixed syntax for building nested resource

Comment: When I try that I get "undefined method `build' for #<User:0x007fb028666bd0>"

Comment: Ha. Now: "undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass" :)

Comment: I edited your answer and it was accepted but you changed it again. It should be `build_home` and `build_work`

Comment: There's a good guide on railscasts on this subject http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast

Comment: It looks like @Sasha has the gist of it, just missed that small detail.

Comment: Sure, just trying to be helpful.  I don't always get it perfect either :)

Comment: Thanks, guys! That's a weird-looking automagical method, but it works!